# Excel Macro - Copy Range Of Cells in Sheet2 to Sheet 1 below Cell With Specific Text

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do is the following using an Excel Macro.

1. Go to Sheet 2 Copy Range of text L3 to R26
2. Then go back to Sheet 1 search for cell containing text "Recess Size" in column L
3. Then paste copied Range starting at cell containing "Recess Size"
4. This needs to repeat until the end of the column.

This is the code I have come up with using the Microsoft Support Page

```
Dim x As Integer
NumRows = Range("L2", Range("L600").End(xldown)).Rows.Count
Range("L2").Select
For x = 1 To NumRows
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1:G24").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Recess Size", After:=ActiveCell,  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
```

Unfortunately this goes into a continuous loop and will not stop until I press ESC and every other occurrence of the action is pasted 1 column to the left?   Is there anything in the code that isn't right?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: If you are Talking about some specific program (like LibreOffice or Excel), please add that information. If it is Excel, the thing you are looking for is "loop". Google for "Excel macro loop" brings results like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299036

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that. It is Excel. Would I just add the code for the loop at the end of the recorded code, or does it need to go in at a certain point?

Comment: Could only be continuous if NumRows changed? You sure it's just not really slow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Would it be possible for you to rejig the code so that it performs the required action?

Answer (score 0):

Activesheet and Activecell are too vague.

If you are working with a multisheet program it is good practice to specify which sheet you are working in or use a "With Sheets("Sheet1")" for a multiple of "Sheet1".

This may not be a cut and paste but you get my meaning:

```
Sub Sheetspractice()
    NumRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:L" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2").Select
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:G24").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="Recess Size", After:=ActiveCell,  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```